# HTML not scrolling to target correctly

Tags: html, scroll, target, scrolltop

I've created an anchor tag as follows

```
<a href="index.html#top">Top</a>
```

And created following tags

```
<h2 id="top">Header</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
   Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
   when an  unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
   specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into 
   electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 
   1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more 
   recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions 
   of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
```

Once clicking on a link, it's scrolling to that `target` but not can't see the `<h2>` tag. So atleast needed to `scroll` above the `target` by `10px or 20px`. Please help me overcome this and the work would be more appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Do like that: add tabindex in

`<h2 id="top" tabindex="1" >Header</h2>`

and use focus()

```
$("#top").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();
```

OR

or the simplest way is that add a anchor tag near h2 and add id="top"

```
<a id="top"></a><h2>Header</h2>
```

but I won't prefer this.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to change href of anchor tag as below

`<a href="#top">Top</a>`

then you can write below jQuery code to get scroll to the target

```
    (function() {
       $('a').click(function() {
           $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#top").offset().top
            }, 3000);
       });
    });
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I usually minus some pixels from the top of the div so my headings appear normal, do this:

```
jQuery('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: jQuery( jQuery(this).attr('href') ).offset().top - 25 
  /* You can minus the pixels */
}, 500);
```